# BPEL designer installation problems

Tags: bpel

I am working on Orchestration of web service and i tried to install of BPEL Designer from eclipse update site http://download.eclipse.org/bpel/site/ from last 2 days but installation stuck to 20 % only and show no progress, no error message or nothing is happing i tired many times but things not working

i use following conflagration

1. Eclipse helios platform 3.6.0
2. Tomcat 7
3. Apache ODE
4. Apache Axis 2
5. JDK 1.6

Help me

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, New Eclipse BPEL designer, requires eclipse Kepler.

But You can download WSO2 DevS ( Download Eclipse JavaEE Kepler + Developer Studio v3.7.0 version) which includes Eclipse BPEL designer with several important bug fixes for xpath editor issue. These fixes are not in Eclipse BPEL designer repo yet.

you can download it from here http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/